# Truncate parent table but not children

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-9.4, truncate

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.4 that I partitioned so that all inserts to the parent actually go into one of the child partitions. The problem is that I already have hundreds of millions of rows of data in the parent table from before I created partitions.

The parent and children exist in different schemas:

parent: `public.history_uint`
children: `partitions.history_uint_p2015_mm_dd`

[Here is how I created the partitions.](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/zabbix2_postgresql_autopartitioning)

How to `TRUNCATE` the parent but not the children?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `ONLY` key word:

```
TRUNCATE ONLY public.history_uint;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html)

> If `ONLY` is specified before the table name, only that table is
>   truncated. If `ONLY` is not specified, the table and all its descendant
>   tables (if any) are truncated. Optionally, `*` can be specified after
>   the table name to explicitly indicate that descendant tables are included.

The schemas where parent and children live are only relevant as far as user privileges on the schema are concerned. Otherwise it's all the same to Postgres.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  I guess next time I'll RTFM instead of SkimmingTFM.

Comment: @sheepdog: SkimmingTFM is still better than the widespread SkippingTFM or the occasional AvoidingTFM. So you're good. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Here child is the table that has foreign key referred to parent table? if so, how can the child table have records when there is no entry in parent table? pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mano: This is not about [FK constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), but about [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) which has been falling out of favor since the advent of [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE).